# Is it possible to populate files in a channel from a directory?

Tags: rocket.chat

I operate a game which maintains various player log files in a directory in .txt format. I would like to mirror all of the .txt files in this directory in a support channel appearing as if you would manually upload them (showing in the right sidebar under files). Is this possible? If so, how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Rocket Chat has an API, but it is under development (https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api). It does not support uploading files.

Another option is for you to post a link to your log files using Rocket Chat's incoming Web Hooks. It allows posting messages from script. (https://rocket.chat/docs/administrator-guides/integrations/#incoming-webhook-scripting)